# How to connect an Arduino Micro to MPU-6050

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-micro, mpu6050

So I'm trying to connect my Arduino micro to the MPU-6050. I was using this tutorial:

https://diyhacking.com/arduino-mpu-6050-imu-sensor-tutorial/

This tutorial worked with my Arduino Uno but not the Micro. When I try to run the Serial Monitor it just says "Initializing I2C Devices".

Is it the code that's not allowing to run it on the Arduino Micro or it needs a different setup than the Arduino Uno?  Thanks!

```cpp
   // I2C device class (I2Cdev) demonstration Arduino sketch for MPU6050 class using DMP (MotionApps v2.0)
// 6/21/2012 by Jeff Rowberg <jeff@rowberg.net>
// Updates should (hopefully) always be available at https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib
//
// Changelog:
//      2013-05-08 - added seamless Fastwire support
//                 - added note about gyro calibration
//      2012-06-21 - added note about Arduino 1.0.1 + Leonardo compatibility error
//      2012-06-20 - improved FIFO overflow handling and simplified read process
//      2012-06-19 - completely rearranged DMP initialization code and simplification
//      2012-06-13 - pull gyro and accel data from FIFO packet instead of reading directly
//      2012-06-09 - fix broken FIFO read sequence and change interrupt detection to RISING
//      2012-06-05 - add gravity-compensated initial reference frame acceleration output
//                 - add 3D math helper file to DMP6 example sketch
//                 - add Euler output and Yaw/Pitch/Roll output formats
//      2012-06-04 - remove accel offset clearing for better results (thanks Sungon Lee)
//      2012-06-01 - fixed gyro sensitivity to be 2000 deg/sec instead of 250
//      2012-05-30 - basic DMP initialization working

/* ============================================
  I2Cdev device library code is placed under the MIT license
  Copyright (c) 2012 Jeff Rowberg

  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
  THE SOFTWARE.
  ===============================================
*/

// I2Cdev and MPU6050 must be installed as libraries, or else the .cpp/.h files
// for both classes must be in the include path of your project
#include "I2Cdev.h"

#include "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h"
//#include "MPU6050.h" // not necessary if using MotionApps include file

// Arduino Wire library is required if I2Cdev I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE implementation
// is used in I2Cdev.h
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
#include "Wire.h"
#endif

// class default I2C address is 0x68
// specific I2C addresses may be passed as a parameter here
// AD0 low = 0x68 (default for SparkFun breakout and InvenSense evaluation board)
// AD0 high = 0x69
MPU6050 mpu;
//MPU6050 mpu(0x69); // <-- use for AD0 high

/* =========================================================================
   NOTE: In addition to connection 3.3v, GND, SDA, and SCL, this sketch
   depends on the MPU-6050's INT pin being connected to the Arduino's
   external interrupt #0 pin. On the Arduino Uno and Mega 2560, this is
   digital I/O pin 2.
   ========================================================================= */

/* =========================================================================
   NOTE: Arduino v1.0.1 with the Leonardo board generates a compile error
   when using Serial.write(buf, len). The Teapot output uses this method.
   The solution requires a modification to the Arduino USBAPI.h file, which
   is fortunately simple, but annoying. This will be fixed in the next IDE
   release. For more info, see these links:

   http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,109987.0.html
   http://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=958
   ========================================================================= */



// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION" if you want to see the actual
// quaternion components in a [w, x, y, z] format (not best for parsing
// on a remote host such as Processing or something though)
//#define OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION

// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER" if you want to see Euler angles
// (in degrees) calculated from the quaternions coming from the FIFO.
// Note that Euler angles suffer from gimbal lock (for more info, see
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)
//#define OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER

// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL" if you want to see the yaw/
// pitch/roll angles (in degrees) calculated from the quaternions coming
// from the FIFO. Note this also requires gravity vector calculations.
// Also note that yaw/pitch/roll angles suffer from gimbal lock (for
// more info, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)
#define OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL

// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL" if you want to see acceleration
// components with gravity removed. This acceleration reference frame is
// not compensated for orientation, so +X is always +X according to the
// sensor, just without the effects of gravity. If you want acceleration
// compensated for orientation, us OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL instead.
//#define OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL

// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL" if you want to see acceleration
// components with gravity removed and adjusted for the world frame of
// reference (yaw is relative to initial orientation, since no magnetometer
// is present in this case). Could be quite handy in some cases.
//#define OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL

// uncomment "OUTPUT_TEAPOT" if you want output that matches the
// format used for the InvenSense teapot demo
//#define OUTPUT_TEAPOT



#define LED_PIN 13 // (Arduino is 13, Teensy is 11, Teensy++ is 6)
bool blinkState = false;

// MPU control/status vars
bool dmpReady = false;  // set true if DMP init was successful
uint8_t mpuIntStatus;   // holds actual interrupt status byte from MPU
uint8_t devStatus;      // return status after each device operation (0 = success, !0 = error)
uint16_t packetSize;    // expected DMP packet size (default is 42 bytes)
uint16_t fifoCount;     // count of all bytes currently in FIFO
uint8_t fifoBuffer[64]; // FIFO storage buffer

// orientation/motion vars
Quaternion q;           // [w, x, y, z]         quaternion container
VectorInt16 aa;         // [x, y, z]            accel sensor measurements
VectorInt16 aaReal;     // [x, y, z]            gravity-free accel sensor measurements
VectorInt16 aaWorld;    // [x, y, z]            world-frame accel sensor measurements
VectorFloat gravity;    // [x, y, z]            gravity vector
float euler[3];         // [psi, theta, phi]    Euler angle container
float ypr[3];           // [yaw, pitch, roll]   yaw/pitch/roll container and gravity vector

// packet structure for InvenSense teapot demo
uint8_t teapotPacket[14] = { '$', 0x02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x00, 0x00, '\r', '\n' };



// ================================================================
// ===               INTERRUPT DETECTION ROUTINE                ===
// ================================================================

volatile bool mpuInterrupt = false;     // indicates whether MPU interrupt pin has gone high
void dmpDataReady() {
  mpuInterrupt = true;
}



// ================================================================
// ===                      INITIAL SETUP                       ===
// ================================================================

void setup() {
  // join I2C bus (I2Cdev library doesn't do this automatically)
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
  Wire.begin();
  TWBR = 24; // 400kHz I2C clock (200kHz if CPU is 8MHz)
#elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE
  Fastwire::setup(400, true);
#endif

  // initialize serial communication
  // (115200 chosen because it is required for Teapot Demo output, but it's
  // really up to you depending on your project)
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial); // wait for Leonardo enumeration, others continue immediately

  // NOTE: 8MHz or slower host processors, like the Teensy @ 3.3v or Arduino
  // Pro Mini running at 3.3v, cannot handle this baud rate reliably due to
  // the baud timing being too misaligned with processor ticks. You must use
  // 38400 or slower in these cases, or use some kind of external separate
  // crystal solution for the UART timer.

  // initialize device
  Serial.println(F("Initializing I2C devices..."));
  mpu.initialize();

  // verify connection
  Serial.println(F("Testing device connections..."));
  Serial.println(mpu.testConnection() ? F("MPU6050 connection successful") : F("MPU6050 connection failed"));

  // wait for ready
  Serial.println(F("\nSend any character to begin DMP programming and demo: "));
  while (Serial.available() && Serial.read()); // empty buffer
  while (!Serial.available());                 // wait for data
  while (Serial.available() && Serial.read()); // empty buffer again

  // load and configure the DMP
  Serial.println(F("Initializing DMP..."));
  devStatus = mpu.dmpInitialize();

  // supply your own gyro offsets here, scaled for min sensitivity
  mpu.setXGyroOffset(220);
  mpu.setYGyroOffset(76);
  mpu.setZGyroOffset(-85);
  mpu.setZAccelOffset(1788); // 1688 factory default for my test chip

  // make sure it worked (returns 0 if so)
  if (devStatus == 0) {
    // turn on the DMP, now that it's ready
    Serial.println(F("Enabling DMP..."));
    mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);

    // enable Arduino interrupt detection
    Serial.println(F("Enabling interrupt detection (Arduino external interrupt 0)..."));
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), dmpDataReady, RISING);
    mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();

    // set our DMP Ready flag so the main loop() function knows it's okay to use it
    Serial.println(F("DMP ready! Waiting for first interrupt..."));
    dmpReady = true;

    // get expected DMP packet size for later comparison
    packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();
  } else {
    // ERROR!
    // 1 = initial memory load failed
    // 2 = DMP configuration updates failed
    // (if it's going to break, usually the code will be 1)
    Serial.print(F("DMP Initialization failed (code "));
    Serial.print(devStatus);
    Serial.println(F(")"));
  }

  // configure LED for output
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
}



// ================================================================
// ===                    MAIN PROGRAM LOOP                     ===
// ================================================================

void loop() {
  // if programming failed, don't try to do anything
  if (!dmpReady) return;

  // wait for MPU interrupt or extra packet(s) available
  while (!mpuInterrupt && fifoCount < packetSize) {
    // other program behavior stuff here
    // .
    // .
    // .
    // if you are really paranoid you can frequently test in between other
    // stuff to see if mpuInterrupt is true, and if so, "break;" from the
    // while() loop to immediately process the MPU data
    // .
    // .
    // .
  }

  // reset interrupt flag and get INT_STATUS byte
  mpuInterrupt = false;
  mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();

  // get current FIFO count
  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

  // check for overflow (this should never happen unless our code is too inefficient)
  if ((mpuIntStatus & 0x10) || fifoCount == 1024) {
    // reset so we can continue cleanly
    mpu.resetFIFO();
    Serial.println(F("FIFO overflow!"));

    // otherwise, check for DMP data ready interrupt (this should happen frequently)
  } else if (mpuIntStatus & 0x02) {
    // wait for correct available data length, should be a VERY short wait
    while (fifoCount < packetSize) fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

    // read a packet from FIFO
    mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);

    // track FIFO count here in case there is > 1 packet available
    // (this lets us immediately read more without waiting for an interrupt)
    fifoCount -= packetSize;

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION
    // display quaternion values in easy matrix form: w x y z
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    Serial.print("quat\t");
    Serial.print(q.w);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(q.x);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(q.y);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(q.z);
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER
    // display Euler angles in degrees
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetEuler(euler, &q);
    Serial.print("euler\t");
    Serial.print(euler[0] * 180 / M_PI);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(euler[1] * 180 / M_PI);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(euler[2] * 180 / M_PI);
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
    // display Euler angles in degrees
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);
    Serial.print("ypr\t");
    Serial.print(ypr[0] * 180 / M_PI);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(ypr[1] * 180 / M_PI);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(ypr[2] * 180 / M_PI);
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL
    // display real acceleration, adjusted to remove gravity
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);
    Serial.print("areal\t");
    Serial.print(aaReal.x);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(aaReal.y);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(aaReal.z);
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL
    // display initial world-frame acceleration, adjusted to remove gravity
    // and rotated based on known orientation from quaternion
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);
    mpu.dmpGetLinearAccelInWorld(&aaWorld, &aaReal, &q);
    Serial.print("aworld\t");
    Serial.print(aaWorld.x);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(aaWorld.y);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(aaWorld.z);
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_TEAPOT
    // display quaternion values in InvenSense Teapot demo format:
    teapotPacket[2] = fifoBuffer[0];
    teapotPacket[3] = fifoBuffer[1];
    teapotPacket[4] = fifoBuffer[4];
    teapotPacket[5] = fifoBuffer[5];
    teapotPacket[6] = fifoBuffer[8];
    teapotPacket[7] = fifoBuffer[9];
    teapotPacket[8] = fifoBuffer[12];
    teapotPacket[9] = fifoBuffer[13];
    Serial.write(teapotPacket, 14);
    teapotPacket[11]++; // packetCount, loops at 0xFF on purpose
#endif

    // blink LED to indicate activity
    blinkState = !blinkState;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, blinkState);
  }
}
```

** code with `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), dmpDataReady, RISING);`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That IMU and library require an interrupt to work correctly.  It is programmed to use interrupt 0 with this line in the setup function: `attachInterrupt(0, dmpDataReady, RISING);` This is not the proper way to do things since it cannot be transferred between arduinos.  On the Uno, interrupt 0 is pin 2 but on the Micro interrupt 0 is pin 3.  So the simple solution is to move the wire from pin 2 to pin 3.  The correct way to fix it is to change the line to this: `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), dmpDataReady, RISING);`

Comment: ok so that didn't work, I switched the wire from pin 2 to pin 3 and updated the attachInterrupt part. It still doesn't work and just says "Initializing I2C devices". I don't know why it isnt working! maybe something else in the program?

Comment: Did you switch the wire and change the code at the same time?  You should only do one of those.

Comment: ok so I tried it all and still doesnt work. I changed the pin and used original code, didn't work. I didnt change the pin and modified the code and it didnt work. I don't know whats wrong and why it doesn't work. It just keeps saying "Initializing I2C devices" and it doesn't doesnt work. I noticed though that when I have the Interrupt wire on pin 2 and with the modified code, it just says " initializing I2C" but then when I take the connect out of pin 2 it then says to press any letter to start. I think its something in the code i dont know. Anymore ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: You've got me then.  Try switching the sda and scl lines?  Try using 4.7kohm pullup resisters on each of those lines (resister goes between that line and 5v)?  Check to make sure the imu is correctly powered?  Finally I might delete the first 7 lines of the setup function and replace it with:
  Wire.begin();
  TWBR = 24;

Comment: yah I keep testing the mpu-6050 with the arduino uno and micro. It always works with the uno but just keeps " initializing I2C devices" on the micro. Could there be something else besides the attachInterrupt() that could not be allowing it to run with the micro?

Comment: Hey so I was looking through the pin-mapping of the micro and it says that  pin 2/SDA and pin 3(PWM)/SCL. I put the link of the mico pin-mapping and it seems that maybe pin 2 and 3 are perhaps interfering. Is it possible to change the code to another interrupt outside of pin 2 and 3? https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoMicro_Pinout3.png

Comment: I put on pin 7 for interrupt and the serial monitor now says "Initializing I2C devices" then says "Testing Device connections" then states "MPU6050 connection failed" then says "Send any character to begin DMP programming and demo:".   So aready by changing to pin 7 it seems to run something vs when I put it on pin 2 or 3 it just says " initializing I2C devices". What do you think? I am I going in the right path?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right path.  The Micro has interrupts on pins 0, 1, 2, 3, and 7.  SDA is now pin 2 and SCL is now pin 3.  I had been assuming that you were using the correct SDA and SCL pins but were you still using pins 4 and 5?  If you are currently using pins 2 and 3 for I2C and pin 7 for the interrupt then I have no idea why it isn't connecting.

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! IT WORKSSSSS I LOVE YOU!!!!...thanks

Comment: actually I just checked and now the program stops running after 10 seconds. Is there something else I should be doing so it runs until I tell it to stop running?

Answer (score 1):

I used interrupt 4 on pin 7 and it worked great! Just had to change the interrupt pin designation to "7" in the code....

Comment: Welcome to the Arduino SE community. Can you please edit your answer to provide more detail? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example or a code snippet, to show where the change needs to be. As it stands, your answer is rather terse.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been through a similar issue, and here's what worked for me.

Following @mwwalk's instruction I changed the interrupt pin to digital Pin 7. After uploading the code to the Arduino Micro it would get past `Initializing I2C devices...` but end up showing `MPU6050 connection failed`. This is because `mpu.testConnection()` was unsuccessful.

To fix this I changed the connections for SCL and SDA on the MPU-6050 to digital pin 3 and digital pin 2 on the Arduino. These aren't the same as the pins shown in the diagram in the tutorial (A5 and A4).

The [pin mapping for the Arduino Micro](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping32u4) lists Digital Pin 2 as the SDA pin and Digital Pin 3 as the SCL pin. Connecting SDA to Digital Pin 2 and SCL to Digital Pin 3 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wait and be patient. It is initializing the sensor. Have you even waited for like 10 seconds? I bet not.

1. Run it and let it wait for 10 seconds.
2. Add `while(!Serial);` right after `Serial.begin(115200);`.
3. Set the baud rate to 115200. It works better in my opinion.
4. Any other devices connected to your I2C constellation? If yes, remove all for testing purposes
5. If it still doesn't work, reboot your PC.

Comment: ok so I tried that and it still doesn't work. It has been almost 30mins where it just says "Initializing I2C devices". I rebooted my computer and re-uploaded the program and it keeps giving me that. Also the "while(!serial);" already exists after the "serial.begin(115200);". I don't know why it isn't working still.

Comment: Post your code, it might be time for some surgery!

Comment: I took the code that was given in the link I put on my original post. Also how do I post my code on here? I'm new to this

Comment: Just copy paste, I'll edit it for you.

Comment: it says I need 10 reputations to have another post. Also when I copy and paste onto this box the code goes over the character limit. Is there somehow I can send it to you?

Comment: Edit the question. Paste your code. Select you whole code. Use this function `{}`in the question/answer editor.

Comment: yah thats exactly what I did and it says I need 10 reputations to post it. Is there some different way I can get you the code?

Comment: hey I was finally allowed to post the program